# Alfresco ip address 127.0.0.1

Tags: ip, alfresco

I have done a Java backed webscript in Alfresco. 
In this webscript I want to get remote ip address.

```
System.out.println("L'objet httpRequest n'est pas null");
ipAdress  =  httpRequest.getRemoteHost();
```

But ip address always returns 127.0.0.1.

The webscript is hosted in `tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\lib` and its declaration in the file `\tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\web-client-application-context.xml`

Have I missed something?

Comment: Are you accessing these webscripts via Alfresco Share perhaps?

Comment: Yes I'm accessing the webscript via Share app. 
Perhaps i  have to put the webscript in Share ?? If yes how can i do that ?

Comment: If you're accessing it via Share, then Share will see your real IP, and Alfresco will see the IP of Share. Why not deploy the webscript to Share instead?

Comment: Because i don't know how to deploy and call  a  share side webscript.
In alfresco documentation i can't see a  tutorial showing cleary  how to make the webscript and where  to put webscript files.

Comment: Process is almost identical, just that you put it in the Share webapp rather than the Alfresco one!

Comment: Ok I see. So in share i'll put the jar in share/web-inf/lib. But where will i put the webscript declaration xml file ? Last can i call this share webscript in a javascript webscript  with the remote root object ?

Comment: Just register it as a java-backed webscript, no need to have javascript trying to call it. You probably need to read some of the Alfresco developer guide, and some tutorials, you don't seem to have the basic level of Alfresco knowledge to really tackle this stuff right now...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96439/discussion-between-soung-and-gagravarr).